# Jenkins / Vagrant / VirtualBox - Virtualbox is running as the system user?

Tags: windows, jenkins, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm pretty new to both VirtualBox and Vagrant, but not Jenkins.  I have a Jenkins build being run on a Windows slave that is running "vagrant up" in a specific directory.  There was a problem with the VM- I went to that directory and tried to manually run vagrant up and it started recloning the box.  Investigating, the VirtualBox VMs folder is being stored in /Windows/system32... I have looked and the Jenkins process and the VirtualBox process are definately being run as the user account that is running the jenkins slave.  If I log into that account and launch virtualbox, it looks for VMs in the account home directory though!

I could probably fix this by pointing both accounts to a third location, but I would like to understand why this is happening.  Any takers?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html), since VirtualBox 4.0, the default location where virtual machines are saved is the current system user's home directory. So:

1. `C:\Documents and Settings\<username>` on Windows
2. `/Users/<username>` on Mac OS X
3. `/home/<username>` on Linux and Solaris

Take a look at the `Default Machine Folder` settings of the virtualbox on your Windows slave to see if anyone has changed the path to `/Windows/System32`

```
File > Preferences > General > Default Machine Folder
```

Also, I am assuming you are using the jenkins [vagrant plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Vagrant+Plugin) to spawn your vagrant box? (If not, you should). AFAIK, that plugin doesn't require any system administrator privilege on the slave machine.

Comment: The vagrant plugin for Jenkins doesn't support recent versions of either jenkins or vagrant, and doesn't support slave machines.  When I log in as the service account and run Virtualbox, it stores machines at C:/Users/<username>.  It seems as though when it is running as a service, virtualbox thinks it is logged in as the system instead of a user, but I've never had any other applications behave that way.

Comment: What command are you using to run vb as a service? Something like `VBoxHeadless.exe  -s {vm_name} -v on` or `VBoxManage.exe" startvm {uuid} --type headless`?

Comment: That's a good question- I am not.  I run Jenkins as a service, which executes Vagrant, which executes virtualbox.  I will have to do some research to see what command vagrant uses...

Comment: So if you aren't using the jenkins vagrant plugin, then there must be some home-brew scripts under the `Configure` section of the build job, which triggers `vagrant up` in the slave box.

Comment: No, its being executed as a shell script in the "build" section.  Like "cd folder; vagrant up; vagrant ssh -c myscript"